# MongoDB $lookup return only one document

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have this function:

```
static getSingleSpaceWithLookup = ( spaceId ) => {
        const db = getDb();
        return db.collection( process.env.SPACECOLLECTION ).aggregate( [
            {
                $match:
                    {
                        $expr:
                            { $eq: [ "$_id", spaceId ] },
                    },
                $lookup: {
                    from: "users",
                    let: { challengers: "$challengers" },
                    pipeline: [
                        {
                            $match:
                                {
                                    $expr:
                                        { $in: [ "$_id", "$$challengers" ] },
                                },

                        },
                        { $limit: 1 },
                        {
                            $project: {
                                password: 0,
                                tokens: 0,
                                friends: 0,
                                incomingFriendRequest: 0,
                                incomingSpaceInvites: 0,
                                spaces: 0
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    as: "members"
                }
            }
        ] ).toArray();
    };
```

And I have this variable with an ID (this is the ID i want to query with)

```
5e1c813bf0941a22a9c440ee
```

ERROR

`MongoError: A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field.`

This returns 3 documents (all of them). Instead, I would like to specify what document to ONLY get, with _id as criteria.

Is this possible?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you be more clear *Instead, I would like to specify what document to ONLY get, but _id criteria.*

Comment: I have three documents, three different Ids. I want to retrieve only one of them. 

I have this ID in a variable "1231451235", I would like to use that to query and only receive that document with the correct $lookup as it is. @Ashh

Comment: Use `{ $limit: 1 }` after `$match` stage.

Comment: Not doing it. Also, that would limit to 1, yes, however not give me the specific document that I want @Ashh

Comment: Please share collection at jsoneditor online ?

Comment: Okay... Do this way `{
                                    $expr:
                                        { $eq: [ "$_id", your_idVariableHere ] }
                                }`

Comment: @Ashh look at the lookup its already matching on _id for the looked up documents, which makes me think he just needs to add a $match before the $lookup

Comment: @tomslabbaert just wait and let him be more clear.

Comment: Not working, although feels like getting closer. I updated the comment so you see the full picture of the function. 

The spaceId is the ID I want to query with. @Ashh

Comment: then put the `$match` stage before the `$lookup` stage.

Comment: `([
    { $match: { _id: ObjectId(spaceId) }},
    {      $lookup: {
        from: "users",
        let: { challengers: "$challengers" },
        pipeline: [
          {
            $match: {
              $expr: { $in: ["$_id", "$$challengers"] }
            }
          },
          {
            $project: {
              password: 0,
              tokens: 0,
              friends: 0,
              incomingFriendRequest: 0,
              incomingSpaceInvites: 0,
              spaces: 0
            }
          }
        ],
        as: "members"
      }
    }
  ])
`

Comment: It Works! Thank you so much for your patience! :) @Ashh